# How to consistently set background-image on HTML element

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, background-image

I'm talking about the `<html>` element itself, seems to work in most browsers, but IE7/8 doesn't want to play. The reason I'm even doing this is because my chore is to theme a RoboHelp web output which uses a million frames - I need to set the topmost frameset's background image otherwise background-positions don't line up when a nested frame invokes a vertical scrollbar.

I tried applying `height:100%;` on the `<html>` element also. Solution must work in IE6+. Javascript should be avoided.

EDIT:

Clarification: I'm applying `style="background: transparent url(image.gif) left top no-repeat;"` to the `html` element via a style block in the header (everything is dynamic, this is my only available method of accessing the html element).

Good heavens, just tested this on a basic page - fine. Replace the body tag with a frameset, like in my situation, and now the images don't show up. This looks to be IE-frameset specific, any suggestions?

Comment: Remember to set the "background-color: #fff;" as well, this used to be a bug in IE6 at least.

Comment: No decent answers and my deadline has passed, I made do with a complete botch job, since the system I was theming was also that. I'll put this down to IE sucking.

Comment: if you've answered your question, provide a detailed answer and accept it. I merged your previous answer into a comment, because it might block someone who has a great answer to share it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I completely understand your problem. But applying `height` to an `HTML` element is a definite no-no. You can apply a background directly to the entire page using the HTML selector

```
html { 
        background-image: url("../images/background_image.png"); 
     }
```

Hint: the '..' in the above example moves to the previous web directory. Be cognizant of your file structure.

Comment: The image appears in other browsers, the file path is correct. The HTML tag is not picking up the background styles in IE7/8. Is my usage of the background shortcut somehow bugged in IE?

Comment: Can you link to an example? I would suggest using CSS. It should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using CSS instead of HTML background image tag. Background image in HTML is now deprecated (outdated and not recommended) by the W3C.

Something like this:

```
<html class="imageBox">
<style type="text/css">
.imageBox {
  width:300;
  height:100;
  background: url("/foobar.gif") #ff9900 90% 30% no-repeat fixed
}
</style>
<p>This div element has a background-image.</p>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the html element itself, I can only add the style block as mentioned in my q edit.